# After upgrade Magento 2.4.2 to 2.4.4 search functionality is not working due to elastic search

Tags: magento2.4, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

After upgrade Magento 2.4.2 to 2.4.4 search functionality is not working due to elastic search.

Even category products are showing fine. I have done reindex , cache flush , setup upgrade.

In log i am getting below details .

```
[2022-07-06T03:29:18.028510+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"[match_phrase_prefix] analyzer [prefix_search] not found","index_uuid":"y4Js58-bRZyQPFUqodoBRg","index":"magento2_product_1_v25"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v25","node":"GN_pI799Tl2S6unB-agkfw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"[match_phrase_prefix] analyzer [prefix_search] not found","index_uuid":"y4Js58-bRZyQPFUqodoBRg","index":"magento2_product_1_v25"}}]},"status":400} in /vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:693
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I am also facing same issue? Did you find solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use ElastiSearch 7 , And

you want to check

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search >
elastic server > test connection button.
```

you can check which search engine :

```
bin/magento config:show catalog/search/engine
bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
```

and also check in database "core_config_data" : path = "catalog/search/"

```
if you have some custom attributes in catalog, you should 
include them in the search so they can be properly indexed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below command in your cmd and then run re-indexing command

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/*
```

Replace localhsot and port(9200) with your host and port

Answer (score 0):

you also can fix this by setting Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Search->Search Engine to none.
https://xxxxx/admin/system_config/edit/section/catalog/

Do not forget to reindex and clear cache.